# Taking User Input in SQL SELECT TOP query

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to acquire the sum of the least n number of values from a table

```
Dim lot As String = "SELECT SUM(x2) AS x3 FROM (SELECT TOP '" & _TextBox2.Text & "' x1 As x2  
                     FROM (
                           SELECT SharePrice As x1 
                           FROM  Shares  
                           WHERE(Company = '" & _TextBox1.Text & "' AND Availability = True)  
                           ORDER BY SharePrice ASC  )
                           )"
```

I dont have problems witha nything else but the TOP '" & _TextBox2.Text & "'  part
Does the SELECT TOP really take parameters in?

I can replace the textbox reference with a hard coded integer and it works. But i want to make it run In visual Basic with user input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use single quotes around the number in the TOP n portion of the query.

Change:

```
SELECT TOP '" & _TextBox2.Text & "'
```

To:

```
SELECT TOP " & _TextBox2.Text & "
```

I also recommend that you use a parametrized query to help prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I don't think you can parameterize the number of rows passed to top.  He can paramterize the where clause but you may want to mention in your answer so the OP doesn't try to parameterize both and get another error.

Comment: This worked for me! I will also consider using parameterized queries

Comment: @Vulcronos [parameterizing TOP works fine](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206977/test-top-as-param?Top=10&UserId=2788838)

Comment: @ConradFrix Really?  I am honestly surprised.  Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Vulcronos of course I am assuming SQL Server 2005 or later. If the OP is using SQL Compact or Access you're stuck doing dynamic sql

Comment: @ConradFrix Yeah, we have to assume the db version he is using.  It could be Oracle for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to do this as a parameterized query. In addition to preventing sql injection attacks it avoids the problems of when to put quotes around things.

In order to get Top to work you will need to surround the parameter name with parens

```
Dim lot As String =  " SELECT SUM(x2) AS x3 
                       FROM 
                     (SELECT TOP (@Top) x1 As x2 
                      FROM (SELECT 
                        SharePrice As x1 
                     FROM  Shares 
                       WHERE    
                   (Company = @CompanyName 
                     AND Availability = True)  
                       ORDER BY SharePrice ASC  ))"


  Dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand (connection, lot)
  cmd.AddWithValue (@Top, Int32.Parse(_TextBox2.Text))
  cmd.AddWithValue (@CompanyName, _TextBox1.Text)
```